# JavaScript toUpperCase only first letter

Tags: javascript, html, css

So again: I'm learning here!
Sorry for such basic questions but I've gotta learn...

Using a trick I read about online I'm trying to adapt it from cap all to cap first letters. See code here - specifically we are looking at the JavaScript `onkeyup`:

This works:

```
<label for="class">Classification</label>
<input type="text" name="class" id="class" value="" required="true" placeholder="" style="text-transform:uppercase" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" />
```

This does not work:

```
<label for="judge">Judge's Name</label>
<input type="text" name="judge" id="judge" value="" required="true" placeholder="" list="judges" style="text-transform:capitalize" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.substr(1);" />
```

Comment: `this.charAt` is not a function, it’s supposed to be `this.value.charAt(0)`. Same for `this.substr`. Look at the console in your browser (press F12). It will tell you the errors.

Comment: Yes it seems I left out .value in 2 spots. Thank you for reminding me to use F12 console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just missed to retrieve `value` property, you need to apply `charAt` and `substr` to a string not directly to the dom element.

```html
<label for="judge">Judge's Name</label>
<input type="text" name="judge" id="judge" value="" required="true" placeholder="" list="judges" style="text-transform:capitalize" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.value.substr(1);" />
```

---

**FYI :** Always it's better to use css, since there is option for capitalizing first letter(using [`text-transform:capitalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform#capitalize_(General))). Also instead of inline script code use a function, to make it more readable and easy to handle.

---

**UPDATE :**
An another advice is to use Html5 `input` event instead of `keyup` which may be much better.

```html
<label for="judge">Judge's Name</label>
<input type="text" name="judge" id="judge" value="" required="true" placeholder="" list="judges" style="text-transform:capitalize" oninput="javascript:this.value=this.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.value.substr(1);" />
```

---

Also you can avoid the problem of moving arrow key(as *@stdob* commented) by adding an additional hidden input field with name `judge` and update value to that field and transfer it to the server.

```js
function transform(ele) {
  var hid = document.getElementById('judge');
  hid.value =
    ele.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + ele.value.substr(1);
}
```

```html
<label for="judge">Judge's Name</label>
<input type="text" value="" required="true" placeholder="" list="judges" style="text-transform:capitalize" onkeyup="transform(this)" />
<input type="hidden" name="judge" id="judge" value="" />
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the script is just unnecessary since OP's already solved the problem with CSS.

Comment: I didn’t downvote. I upvoted only this answer, because this is the only answer addressing the actual problem _and_ explaining it _and_ providing a working solution. Maybe it’s because you didn’t mention `addEventListener`.

Comment: This is not actually addressing the problem, since there's no problem, @Xufox. The script which OP uses is useless - it doesn't matter whether it have errors or not - it can be just removed.

Comment: @nicael There’s a pretty obvious problem with the JavaScript. OP’s JS code results in TypeErrors. This needs to be fixed in any case. Either by removing the script or by fixing it.

Comment: And hence I don't get why my solution to [remove the script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37887620) got those weird downvotes...

Comment: Keys "left" and "right" will not allow you to move through the text - the carriage is moved to the end of the text after any key is pressed. At least in Safari.

Comment: i've been gone all day so i'm just getting back to this issue... Seems that CSS IS NOT THE SOLUTION! CSS only transforms, it does not actually change the real data that will be used later in a database. So the JS is NECESSARY - the added inline CSS simply makes it look better as the form is filled out. Without the CSS you get a funny moment where the case is lower then transforms into upper. So really the CSS is redundant here.